# Installing and running VMWare Workstation 10 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, vmware

I'm having trouble installing and running VMWare Workstation 10 on Ubuntu 14.04.

I've tried the vast majority of posts I have found on this topic and none of them have resolved my issue. I have uninstalled VMWare and reinstalled it to get back to a known point and will happily cover old ground again to try and resolve the issue. My thinking is that it's better to start from a known point and post everything that goes wrong individually so that it helps others with the same problem rather than starting halfway through the fix.

The only thing that I ask is that people explain how to do certain steps, for instance instead of saying "just untar the tarball edit the "*.config" file, would you please explain how to do that?

When I try to run the application it produces an alert which tells me to check a log file. Upon checking the log file, the last couple of entries are (can get more if required):

```
2016-02-16T15:04:23.286Z| vthread-3| I120: Setting destination path for vmnet to "/lib/modules/3.19.0-25-generic/misc/vmnet.ko".
2016-02-16T15:04:23.286Z| vthread-3| I120: Extracting the vmnet source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmnet.tar".
2016-02-16T15:04:23.290Z| vthread-3| I120: Successfully extracted the vmnet source.
2016-02-16T15:04:23.290Z| vthread-3| I120: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j8 -C /tmp/modconfig-TT9hWO/vmnet-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.19.0-25-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2016-02-16T15:04:24.202Z| vthread-3| W110: Failed to build vmnet.  Failed to execute the build command.
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

--------------------------------- Update -------------------------------------

So I decided to carry on trying to fix this myself. This is what I've tried so far, but growing increasingly desperate:

Workstation 10.0.6 downloaded and installed without any issues. On first run, VMWare produces an error stating:

"Unable to start services.

See log file /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-modconfig-9432.log for details."

Upon investigation of that log I discovered it was failing here:

```
2016-02-18T11:27:59.249Z| vthread-3| I120: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j8 -C /tmp/modconfig-07fLDu/vmnet-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.19.0-49-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2016-02-18T11:28:00.176Z| vthread-3| W110: Failed to build vmnet.  Failed to execute the build command.
```

I have looked online and there seems to be a lot of trouble with this. I tried to apply the fix mentioned here: [Error Installing Vmware Workstation On Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449629/error-installing-vmware-workstation-on-ubuntu) however, this creates an error

```
Hunk #3 FAILED at 259.
1 out of 3 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file vmnet-only/filter.c.rej
```

I looked into what this error was and it produces this:

```
*** /dev/null
--- /dev/null
***************
*** 259
- transmit = (hooknum == VMW_NF_INET_POST_ROUTING);
--- 263,267 -----
+ #if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(3, 13, 0)
+ transmit = (hooknum == VMW_NF_INET_POST_ROUTING);
+ #else
+ transmit = (ops->hooknum == VMW_NF_INET_POST_ROUTING);
+ #endif
```

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: you can also use `virtualbox` if you want

Comment: I can't unfortunately. I need to use this specific variant of VMWare Workstation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I raised a service ticket with VMWare who in turn informed me that VMWare 10 was not compatible with this Kernel version due to the age of the product. VMWare upgraded my product to VMWare Workstation 12 which I downloaded, installed, and ran without issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `build-essential`

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

To execute:

```
 chmod +x VMwarexxxxxxx.bundle
```

and

```
./VMwarexxxxxxx.bundle
```

Comment: I already have the latest version of `build-essential`.